# Vector<int> factory with initialization is not working

Tags: c++, visual-studio, clang

I have tried to create a vector factory that creates a vector of `1` values of specified size `s` but is not working as expected.

```
template<size_t s>
constexpr std::vector<int>& vector_factory()
{
    std::vector<int> v(s, 1);
    return v;
}


int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    constexpr size_t s = 10;
    std::vector<int> v1 = vector_factory<s>();
    std::vector<int> v2 = vector_factory<s>();
}
```

I get a runtime error due to the large allocation attempt. However, if I try to implement it like this it is working properly.

```
constexpr size_t s = 10;
std::vector<int> v1(s, 1);
std::vector<int> v2(s, 1);
```

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: You are returning a reference to a local variable `v` which is out of scope after the call to `vector_factory()`

Comment: why do you need a factory? If you like you can call the constructor a "factory" and be done with it

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The runtime error is not due to a large allocation attempt, but due to two dangling references. The function signature

```
constexpr std::vector<int>& vector_factory();
```

has two issues. First, it fails to compile because `std::vector` doesn't have a `constexpr` constructor. Second, you must return the object by value, not by reference. Compilers should even warn you about this problem. If you change the above to

```
std::vector<int> vector_factory() { /* As before... */ }
```

everything should work as expected.

Comment: Why is constexpr an issue? It is not related to vector<int> it is a definition related to the function: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/constexpr

Comment: @RadimBača from your link: "... declares that it is possible to evaluate the value of the function or variable at compile time". Declaring it doesnt mean that it really is possible, you cannot `constexpr` construct a vector

Comment: There is no `constexpr` constructor in [`std::vector`](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/container/vector/vector). I believe that's intended as `std::vector` might do allocation and that's contrary to `constexpr`.

Comment: Ok, I get it now. Thank you for your responses.